# Error when importing keyring library in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pythonanywhere

I keep getting the same error when I import the keyring library. Just adding 'import keyring' to the code causes this error to appear. I have tried installing the library again, but that didn't solve it.

I'm using python 3.5 in pythonanywhere.

Can somebody help me figure out what might be going on or what I else I can try to do to fix it?

This is the Error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/home/Marketscale/Tests/OAuth Test.py", line 3, in <module> import keyring 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible 
File "/home/Marketscale/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keyring-10.3.2-py3.5.egg/keyring/__init__.py", line 6, in <module> 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible 
File "/home/Marketscale/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keyring-10.3.2-py3.5.egg/keyring/core.py", line 149, in <module> 
File "/home/Marketscale/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keyring-10.3.2-py3.5.egg/keyring/core.py", line 65, in init_backend 
File "/home/Marketscale/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keyring-10.3.2-py3.5.egg/keyring/util/__init__.py", line 20, in wrapper 
File "/home/Marketscale/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keyring-10.3.2-py3.5.egg/keyring/backend.py", line 179, in get_all_keyring 
File "/home/Marketscale/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keyring-10.3.2-py3.5.egg/keyring/backend.py", line 139, in _load_backends 
File "/home/Marketscale/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keyring-10.3.2-py3.5.egg/keyring/backend.py", line 131, in _load_backend 
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible 
File "/home/Marketscale/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keyring-10.3.2-py3.5.egg/keyring/backends/SecretService.py", line 9, in <module> 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible 
File "/home/Marketscale/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/SecretStorage-2.3.1-py3.5.egg/secretstorage/__init__.py", line 13, in <module> 
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/__init__.py", line 81, in <module> import dbus.exceptions as exceptions 
AttributeError: module 'dbus' has no attribute 'exceptions'
>>>
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Looks like you need to post the code that's calling for the attribute 'exceptions'

Comment: That's the thing, I don't call anything. The error comes just from 'import keyring'. I have tested that. I made a short code that works, but just adding 'import keyring' to it, without using the library at all causes the error to appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that there's some kind of conflict between one of the system-installed modules and the ones you've installed with `pip install --user` into *~/.local*

I suggest switching to a virtualenv to get a "clean" set of modules/dependencies.  More info here: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Virtualenvs

Comment: Thanks, that helped.